# Installing newer version but still older version active

Tags: rvm

I needed some features from a newer version so  I installed 1.9.3 . However after the installation when I write "ruby --version" it still gives me back 1.8.7.

Any idea how to update it?

I used rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p0 to install it, and this worked on other machines, just not on this one

Comment: What is the output of `rvm current` and `rvm list`?

Comment: I solved it by going to the app directory and writing "rvm ruby-1.9.3-p0"

Comment: If you've solved your problem on your own then I suggest you delete your question so it does not continue to show up as unanswered.

Comment: or write your answer by yourself

Answer (score 1):

there is a shortcut for your needs:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p0 --install --default
```

where:

- `--install` will install this ruby if it is not yet installed
- `--default` will set this ruby default so it will be loaded when you open new shell